# Dynamic sourceURL in HTTP Connection Manger with for each loop

Tags: vb.net, http, ssis, httprequest

I have a SQL -statement that returns multiple ID's. I want to make make a http request for every ID.

Everything works in the first iteration of the loop, butcrashes the second time around. I get the following error:

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

The flow looks like this:

[image]

The code in the script looks like this:

```
Public Sub Main()
        'connecting website using HTTP connection manager
        Dim nativeObject As Object = Dts.Connections("HTTP Connection Manager").AcquireConnection(Nothing)

        ' Create a new HTTP client connection
        Dim connection As New HttpClientConnection(nativeObject)

        'Download the html page to your local drive
        connection.DownloadFile("C:\temp\samtykker.txt", True)

        MsgBox(Dts.Variables("cID").Value.ToString)

        Dim streamReader As New StreamReader("C:\temp\samtykker.txt")

        Dim streamText As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd
        Dts.Variables("fileContent").Value = streamText

        Dim indexWithAnswer As Integer = InStr(10000, streamText, "<span id=""ConsentEntryCtrl_Lbl_SamtykkeMotattMeldingValue"" class=""Text"">", CompareMethod.Text)
        Dim startIndex As Integer = InStr(indexWithAnswer, streamText, "NEI", CompareMethod.Text)

        Dim answer As String = If(startIndex = 0, "JA", streamText.Substring(startIndex - 1, 3))

        MsgBox(answer.ToString())

    End Sub
```

I have not found anything helpful on the web, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You posted the stack trace, but is there an actual error message?

Comment: @the_lotus all the error says is: `Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`